# Is it possible to stop Chrome and other browsers from pre-fetching/rendering my site?

Tags: web-development, browsers, meta-tags

I know you can [guide Chrome to prefetch links you think users are likely to click on your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26873/what-percent-of-visitors-should-click-on-the-next-page-before-you-enable-prefetc), but can you also do the inverse? Can you tell Chrome (or really *any* browser) not to prefetch and prerender your site?

Is there a  tag or other way I can tell browsers that pre-fetching links from the currently viewed page shouldn't be done?

Comment: Curious, why would you want this?

Comment: @Martijn One case that I can see is when your site contains time-dependent or highly dynamic content where a delay between the page rendering and when the user actually *sees* it matter.

Comment: @Martijn Another reason is if your page is a monster that takes forever to load.  We have an internal "rebuild search index" page that takes minutes.  I could see chrome prefetching it, invalidating my tests, especially while restarting the webserver.

Comment: I wonder if requiring a POST request (like from a form) would work in my case.  No browser should ever prefetch that!

Comment: @GlenPeterson Please tell me you have functionality like that behind a logic?! And better, an command instead of a page, some secure background task

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome and Safari send an `X-Purpose: preview` HTTP header when pre-fetching/rendering web content. [[Source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-discuss/t8H-cUkQ1VI%5B1-25%5D)]

Firefox sends a similar header called `X-moz: prefetch`. [[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ)]

To block pre-fetching, you could return a 404 response when such headers are detected, as suggested by Peter Freitag in [this blog post](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/312.cfm). He recommends adding these lines to `.htaccess` to block Firefox prefetching:

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf X-moz prefetch HAS_X-moz 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HAS_X-moz} prefetch 
RewriteRule .* /prefetch-attempt [L]
```

You can extend this to block Firefox, Safari, and Chrome prefetching like this (untested, but should work):

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf X-moz prefetch HAS_preview 
SetEnvIf X-Purpose preview HAS_preview
RewriteCond %{ENV:HAS_preview} .
RewriteRule .* /prefetch-attempt [L]
```

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome does not send any special headers to prerender requests anymore. See:

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86175
- https://github.com/nickhsharp/prefetchNightmare

Answer (score 1):

Above answer did not work for me. What did work, however, was this:

```
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-For .+ proxy=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase X-moz prefetch no_access=yes

# block pre-fetch requests with X-moz headers
RewriteCond %{ENV:no_access} yes
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

From: [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Stop_browser_prefetching)

The [F] flag returns a 403 Forbidden status code to the browser, while the [L] indicates that rule should be the last rule to be processed.

Also, chrome does not seem to prefetch links any longer (at least, for the prev/next meta tags).